# How can I react when an EditText is being focused?

Tags: android

I have an EditText that the user can write in, when the app starts there is already a string in the EditText. When the user clicks the EditText it becomes focused and the curser is where the user clicked the EditText text box.

I know that the code for setting the curser to the start is :

```
editText.setSelection(0);
```

But I don't know where to put this code, I tried to it in beforeTextChanged but it didn't do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting an [putting an OnFocusChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29). You'd do something like this:

```
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
  public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus){
    if(hasFocus){
      ((EditText)view).setSelection(0);
    }
  }
});
```

Where `et` is the text edit you want to set the listener on.

Full-discolsure: haven't tried this code out myself.

Comment: Can you please add code example ?
lets say I have : EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.timeET);

Comment: Just added example. Does that make sense?

Comment: I get : "View.OnFocusChangedListener cannot be resolved to a 
  type"

Comment: did you remember to import the android.view.View class?

Comment: yes, the code kid of works, only needed to change the word "Changed" to "Change" so the code is :    et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
     public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus){
       if(hasFocus){
         ((EditText)view).setSelection(0);
       }
     }
   });

thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

While there is probably a way to do this, I'm not entirely sure it's the best user experience, because when the user taps a text box at a specific spot, they really expect the cursor to be there. Imagine for instance if the user sees "abcd" written there and wants to edit that to "abcde", so they figure "I'll just tap at the end and append an 'e'". Imagine the user's frustration when that doesn't work as expected.

If you expect the user to edit the textbox, I'd consider leaving it empty. If you are using the existing text as a hint ("email@example.com"), it's probably a better idea to indicate that in some other way.

Comment: You can use `setHint(CharSequence)` to display a hint when the EditText is empty of content.

Comment: I will take this into consideration, I only want to help to user and not let him try and get to the beginning of the (small) text box.